# How accurate is robot reaching goal?

Tags: lidar, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a very simple robot with differential steering and Hokuyo Laser range scanner. Our HectorSLAM have only the laser data for the navigation.
Our question is, from your experiences, how accurately can such a robot reach the goal at a distance of 15 meters with plenty of obstacles in its way. We don't need any precipice numbers, estimates are OK, we just need and idea of what to expect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248532/how-accurate-is-robot-reaching-goal?/) by [AtomicFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/28585/atomicfs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That depends on a whole host of factors such as LIDAR used, properties of the environment and how the robot moves, but with a good setup localization noise should be in the low centimeter range (let's say < 5cm). The other factor is robot controller performance, which is very specific for the type of robot used.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my experience, it greatly depends on the accuracy of your odometry and imu data.

---

Originally posted by [FrankYou](https://answers.ros.org/users/28058/frankyou/) with karma: 46 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1